# How can my class which extends an abstract class use its own variables?

Tags: java, sprite

I have two classes which uses several equal methods, so I thought I could use an abstract class instead of an interface to allow the abstract class to have method bodies, and reduce duplication of code in the other classes.
But I get an error saying x is "null" when running my main function, and I believe that is because it uses the empty variable from the abstract class. But for my method in the abstract class I need to declare the variables the methods uses, so how do I get it to use the variables from my subclass? Specifically, the error is in `AGameFigures setPosition()` for `bottom.x = x;`

Here is my code:

```
abstract class AGameFigures {
public Rectangle hitbox;
int action;
ICollision collision;
float tileHeight, tileWidth;
float spriteHeight, spriteWidth;
float velocityY;

public AGameFigures(){
    this.hitbox = hitbox;
    this.action = action;
    this.collision = collision;
    this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
    this.tileWidth =tileWidth;
    this.spriteHeight = spriteHeight;
    this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
    this.velocityY = 0;
}

public void update(float delta) {
    float oldY = hitbox.y;
    hitbox.y += velocityY;
    velocityY -= (25 * delta);

    boolean collisionDown = false;
    boolean collisionUpwards = false;

    if(velocityY < 0) {
        collisionDown = collision.collidesDownwards(hitbox.x, hitbox.y);
    } else if(velocityY > 0) {
        collisionUpwards = collision.collidesUpwards(hitbox.x, hitbox.y);
    }
    if(collisionDown) {
        hitbox.y = (int) (oldY / tileHeight) * tileHeight;
        velocityY = 0;
    }
    if(collisionUpwards) {
        hitbox.y = (int) ((hitbox.y+spriteHeight/2) / tileHeight) * tileHeight;
        if(velocityY > 0)
            velocityY = 0;
        velocityY -= (25 * delta);
    }
}
public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    hitbox.x = x;
    hitbox.y = y;
}

abstract void moveLeft(float delta);

abstract void moveRight(float delta);

public void setVelocityY(float newVelY) {
    velocityY = newVelY;
}
public void jump() {
    if (velocityY == 0)
        velocityY = 7;

}
public int hits(Rectangle r) {
    if(hitbox.overlaps(r))
        return 1;
    return -1;
}
```

}

```
public class GamePlayer extends AGameFigures{

public Rectangle hitbox;
int action;
float tileHeight, tileWidth;
float spriteHeight, spriteWidth;
ICollision collision;
float velocityY;


public GamePlayer(float spriteHeight, float spriteWidth, ICollision collision) {
    hitbox = new Rectangle(0.0f, 0.0f, 128.0f, 128.0f);
    velocityY = 0;
    hitbox.x = 0; hitbox.y = 0;
    tileWidth = collision.getTileWidth(); tileHeight = collision.getTileHeight();
    this.spriteHeight = spriteHeight; this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
    this.collision = collision;
}

public void action(int type, float x, float y) {
    if(type == 1) {
        velocityY = 0;
        setPosition(hitbox.x, y);
    }
}

@Override
public void moveLeft(float delta) {
    hitbox.x -= (200 * delta);  // delta == "change of time" "for fluid change om motion"
    if(collision.collidesLeftwards(hitbox.x, hitbox.y)) {
        hitbox.x = (int) (hitbox.x / tileWidth) * tileWidth + spriteWidth;
    }
}
@Override
public void moveRight(float delta) {
    hitbox.x += (200 * delta);  // (value) * delta, endre value for å endre movementspeed
    if(collision.collidesRightwards(hitbox.x, hitbox.y)) {
        hitbox.x = (int) (hitbox.x / tileWidth) * tileWidth;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From the `AGameFigures` constructor:

```
public AGameFigures(){
    this.hitbox = hitbox;
    ... 
}
```

There are no arguments passed to the constructor, so `hitbox` refers to the class instance field, which is null.  This line of code from the constructor:

```
this.hitbox = hitbox;
```

is effectively:

```
this.hitbox = null;
```

So later on a null ponter is encountered.  The constructor needs to be updated to pass the arguments:

```
public AGameFigures(Rectangle hitbox, ...){
    this.hitbox = hitbox;
    ... 
}
```

and the sub-classes will need to provide the constructor argument values.

`GamePlayer` defines its own `hitbox` which is probably causing some confusion.  `hitbox` should be removed from `GamePlayer`, and just rely on the base class.

Check the compiler warnings, and do not (usually) ignore them!

Answer (score 0):

why you diclare the sames filed in superclass  and subclass

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is in the constructor of the abstract class.
The variables will always be null.

You need to provide params in the constructor:

```
public AGameFigures(Hitbox hitbox, int action, ICollision collision, float tileHeight, float tileWidth, float spriteHeight, float spriteWith, float velocityY){
    this.hitbox = hitbox;
    this.action = action;
    this.collision = collision;
    this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
    this.tileWidth =tileWidth;
    this.spriteHeight = spriteHeight;
    this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
    this.velocityY = 0;
}
```

And, you don't need to repeat the variables which are inherited.